# ¿cómo insertar aleatoriamente, en Python, un porcentaje de missing values en un DataSet?

Tags: python

Cordial saludo.

Estoy trabajando sobre el dataset Forest Fire (https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/forest+fires) y requiero asignar x porcentaje de valores faltantes (missing values) aleatoriamente ¿me pueden indicador cómo hacerlo?

Aquí les adjunto una muestra del data set:

[image: Muestra Jupyter NoteBook]

[image: Descripción de campos]

```
   X  Y  month  day   FFMC   DMC   DC     ISI   temp   RH   wind   rain  area
0  7  5  mar    fri   86.2   26.2  94.3   5.1   8.2    51   6.7    0.0   0.00
1  7  4  oct    tue   90.6   35.4  669.1  6.7   18.0   33   0.9    0.0   0.00 
2  7  4  oct    sat   90.6   43.7  686.9  6.7   14.6   33   1.3    0.0   0.00
3  8  6  mar    fri   91.7   33.3  77.5   9.0   8.3    97   4.0    0.2   0.00
4  8  6  mar    sun   89.3   51.3  102.2  9.6   11.4   99   1.8    0.0   0.00
```

Comment: ¿Qué entiendes por valores faltantes? ¿Se trata de eliminar filas, o de insertar NaN en las celdas?  En el segundo caso ¿en qué columna irían los valores NaN? ¿En columnas aleatorias también? En este caso ¿algunas de las columnas quedarían excluidas de la elección?. Y otra cosa, puedes compartir lo que muestras en el dataframe en forma de texto (quizás un `print(df)` sirva, o si te sale truncado puedes convertir a csv una muestra con `df.head(16).to_csv()` y compartir el csv resultante.

Comment: ¡Hola! sí, debo insertar NaN en todo el DataSet, puntualmente el 10%, en todas las columnas. Soy novato en Python y no sé cómo hacerlo. te adjunto una muestra del DataSet como lo solicitaste (print(df)):

Comment: X  Y month  day  FFMC    DMC     DC   ISI  temp  RH  wind  rain   area
0    7  5   mar  fri  86.2   26.2   94.3   5.1   8.2  51   6.7   0.0   0.00
1    7  4   oct  tue  90.6   35.4  669.1   6.7  18.0  33   0.9   0.0   0.00
2    7  4   oct  sat  90.6   43.7  686.9   6.7  14.6  33   1.3   0.0   0.00
3    8  6   mar  fri  91.7   33.3   77.5   9.0   8.3  97   4.0   0.2   0.00
4    8  6   mar  sun  89.3   51.3  102.2   9.6  11.4  99   1.8   0.0   0.00

Comment: Mil gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un mecanismo muy sencillo aunque no del todo preciso (luego explico por qué) sería como sigue:

- Determinar cuántos elementos tiene el dataframe (multiplicando su número de filas por el de columnas)
- Calcular cuántos deberían ser llenados con NaN (el 10% de la cantidad anterior)
- En un bucle que se itera ese número de veces:

  - Generar al azar un número de fila y uno de columna
  - Asignar `float("nan")` a las coordenadas resultantes.

Esto lo haría el código siguiente:

```
from random import randrange

porcentaje = 10

n_filas, n_columnas = df.shape
numero_nans = (n_filas*n_columnas*porcentaje)//100  # // es la división entera

for i in range(numero_nans):
  fila = randrange(0, n_filas)
  columna = randrange(0, n_columnas)
  df.iloc[fila, columna] = float("nan")
```

Por ejemplo, aplicando esto a tu dataframe me ha salido:

```
   X  Y month  day  FFMC   DMC     DC  ISI  temp    RH  wind  rain  area
0  7  5   mar  fri  86.2  26.2   94.3  5.1   8.2  51.0   6.7   0.0   NaN
1  7  4   oct  tue  90.6  35.4  669.1  6.7  18.0  33.0   NaN   0.0   0.0
2  7  4   oct  sat  90.6   NaN  686.9  6.7   NaN  33.0   1.3   0.0   0.0
3  8  6   NaN  fri  91.7  33.3   77.5  9.0   8.3   NaN   4.0   0.2   0.0
4  8  6   mar  sun  89.3  51.3  102.2  9.6  11.4  99.0   1.8   0.0   0.0
```

Como dije antes esto no es del todo exacto, y el número de NaNs que al final queden insertados podría ser inferior al 10%, ya que no se está verificando si ya se había insertado un NaN en esa misma casilla. Puede dar la casualidad de que se elija dos o más veces la misma, con lo que el número de NaNs total sería inferior al deseado.

De todas formas eso es bastante improbable, y de todas formas ya hay una imprecisión en lo que respecta al 10% pues puede no ser un número entero (como de hecho ocurre en este dataframe que tiene 65 elementos, por lo que el 10% sería introducir 6.5 NaNs, y se ha redondeado a 6).

Para verificar cuántos NaN se han insertado realmente se pueden contar con `df.isna().sum().sum()` (sale 6 en el ejemplo anterior, o sea que no se ha elegido dos veces una misma casilla).

### Otra solución

Otra técnica para que el número de NaN introducidos sea *exactamente* el deseado, pero que sólo es factible cuando el número total de celdas no es muy elevado, sería la siguiente:

- Pre-generar una lista con todos los pares de coordenadas (fila,columna) posibles. La función `itertools.product()` sería de ayuda aqui.
- "Barajar" esa lista para dejarla en orden aleatorio
- Extraer los primeros `numero_nans` elementos de esa lista
- Usarlos para poner NaN en las correspondientes coordenadas.

El código sería así:

```
from itertools import product
from random import shuffle

porcentaje = 10

n_filas, n_columnas = df.shape
coordenadas = list(product(range(n_filas), range(n_columnas)))
shuffle(coordenadas)

numero_nans = (n_filas*n_columnas*porcentaje)//100
for fila, columna in coordenadas[:numero_nans]:
  df.iloc[fila,columna] = float("nan")
```

Si el número de filas fuese muy alto, esta estrategia sería bastante ineficiente porque necesitaría crear en memoria una larga lista de `coordenadas`.

Comment: Mil gracias, con el primer código lo logré hacer.